# How to add context help or a help icon to flux field?

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I'm working on a content element created with [flux](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/flux). Editors using this element can use some markers in some fields (e.g. ###region###). Therefore I would like to give information about the markers that can be used.

I checked [CSH](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-inside/7.6/en-us/CoreArchitecture/ContextSensitiveHelp/Index.html) and the [Flux documentation](https://viewhelpers.fluidtypo3.org/) but couldn't find any solution. Does someone have an idea how to solve this?

My code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
  xmlns:flux="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Flux/ViewHelpers"
  xmlns:v="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Vhs/ViewHelpers"
  data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">

<f:layout name="Content"/>

<f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:form id="tt-teaser">
        <flux:field.input label="Stoerer" name="stoerer"/>
        <flux:field.input label="Title" name="title"/>
        <flux:field.text label="Text" name="text" enableRichText="1"/>
        <flux:field.input label="Button Text" name="buttonText"/>
    </flux:form>
</f:section>
```

I'm using TYPO3 v10.4.13 and Flux v9.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can add LL references for TCA descriptions, the tx_news extension uses this approach as well.
`\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addLLrefForTCAdescr('tt_content.pi_flexform.[extkey-with-no-lower-dash]_[CE-name]', 'EXT:your_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_csh.xlf');`.
As you can see you have to add this for each CE, also the id in the language file is "*[field-ID].description*".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).